# When compiling this error come how to fix this error?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got the error CS0535

> Library\PackageCache\com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@7.1.8\Editor\UniversalRenderPipelineCameraEditor.cs(1049,57): error CS0535: 'UniversalRenderPipelineCameraContextualMenu' does not implement interface member 'IRemoveAdditionalDataContextualMenu.RemoveComponent(Camera, IEnumerable)'

My code is

```
[ScriptableRenderPipelineExtension(typeof(UniversalRenderPipelineAsset))]
class UniversalRenderPipelineCameraContextualMenu : IRemoveAdditionalDataContextualMenu<Camera>
{
    //The call is delayed to the dispatcher to solve conflict with other SRP
    public void RemoveComponent(Camera camera)
    {
        Undo.SetCurrentGroupName("Remove Universal Camera");
        var additionalCameraData = camera.GetComponent<UniversalAdditionalCameraData>();
        if (additionalCameraData)
        {
            Undo.DestroyObjectImmediate(additionalCameraData);
        }
        Undo.DestroyObjectImmediate(camera);
```

Comment: The error message says that you need a second parameter of type `IEnumerable`. See also [Implement an interface in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/implement-interface?view=vs-2019).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a parameter in your RemoveComponent method. It should be `public void RemoveComponent(Camera camera, IEnumerable obj)` or something.

You need to implement all the Interface members from `IRemoveAdditionalDataContextualMenu<Camera>`

You can try pressing `Ctrl` and clicking on `IRemoveAdditionalDataContextualMenu`

You have to implement every one of the methods you see in that interface.
You have to consider the return type (`void`,`int`, etc.), the method name and the exact parameters when implementing members.

Do this and your errors will go away.

From Olivier in the comments: [Use this tutorial if you are using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/implement-interface?view=vs-2019)

Comment: public void RemoveComponent(Camera camera, IEnumerable obj)    replacing this line would work right?

Comment: `Library\PackageCache\com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@7.1.8\Editor\UniversalRenderPipelineCameraEditor.cs(1049,57): error CS0535: 'UniversalRenderPipelineCameraContextualMenu' does not implement interface member 'IRemoveAdditionalDataContextualMenu<Camera>.RemoveComponent(Camera, IEnumerable<Component>)'`

Comment: stilll have the same issue

Comment: @HUSKY I edited my answer. You have to be sure to implement all members of the interface `IRemoveAdditionalDataContextualMenu<Camera>`

Comment: can you make this right? please edit the code for me

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I wouldn't know exactly which Members you have to implement. You have to figure that out on your own by following either what I said or the Tutorial.